# Basic question about eq.subst substitution rules

Tags: lean

I'm trying to learn Lean. I can't understand why the last equality substitution does not work (I'm just trying to "literally" replace `0+c` by a simple `c`):

```
import data.int.basic

example : ∀ {b c : ℤ}, b + c = 0 + c → b + c = c :=
  assume b c : ℤ,
  assume h : b + c = 0 + c,
  have c0 : 0 + c = c, by rw zero_add,
  show b + c = c, from eq.subst c0 h
```

I got the error:

> "eliminator" elaborator type mismatch, term
> h
> has type
> b + c = 0 + c
> but is expected to have type
> b + (0 + c) = 0 + c

Seems to me that Lean is assuming that all occurrences of `c` must have the form `0+c`, which is a bit strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lean uses the expected type of the `show` to determine what `h` should be so it assumes that `h` should come from making the reverse substitution in the goal. This is one reason why using tactics like `rewrite` are much more convenient to use in practice.

One way to get this to work is to do this instead:

```
import data.int.basic

example : ∀ {b c : ℤ}, b + c = 0 + c → b + c = c :=
  assume b c : ℤ,
  assume h : b + c = 0 + c,
  have c0 : 0 + c = c, by rw zero_add,
  show b + c = c, from eq.substr h c0
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about `eq.substr`; from its definition another way would have been `show b + c = c, from eq.subst h.symm c0`.